# Android UI components are changing by their own... Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, components

I am newbie in android development, so I have a little problem. I use relative layout, but my components (buttons, textviews, edittext etc), changes their place when, for example, I change some other component, or even toggle it invisible. I would like to know how can I make them independent one from another? To change place of one, without moving others and so on?

Here is my xml code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.misteriousegg.MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#111111" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Aj da radi brate da se ja onako ne bih nervirao, i tako /n i tako"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:onClick="Funkcija"
    android:text="Pocni!"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
    android:onClick="Funkcija1"
    android:text="Help?"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Zajebancija"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Comment: post ur xml and how r u expecting to behave?

Comment: Here, I posted. I would like to make it somehow not to be relied on each other, because I don't want to change margines of other components, by changing one component...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you used a `RelativeLayout` and as the name already implies the views are organized relatively to each other. So if you define something like `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"` your *Button* will always be placed to the left of your *TextView* and I guess that's not intended since your button will move around when the text changes.
So instead of using a RelativeLayout you should consider using a `LinearLayout` and nest a RelativeLayout inside where it's needed.

Since the whole layout-stuff is essential when developing for Android you should really read the following guide at [developer.android.com (Layouts)](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#CommonLayouts).